# Make custom validations in EXTJS as components

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I have written custom validations like below

```
Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    valInt: function(v) {
        return /^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$/.test(v);
    },
    valIntText: 'Must be in the form #,#',
    valIntMask: /[\d\,]/i
});
```

It works. But i want to make all such custom validation in a single file and then load it or auto load it. How do i do it?

I can do like below in app.js

```
 Ext.onReady(function() {    
  Ext.apply(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
        valInt: function(v) {
            return /^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$/.test(v);
        },
        valIntText: 'Must be in the form #,#',
        valIntMask: /[\d\,]/i
    });
});
```

But then the app.js file will become big after all validations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.form.field.VTypes.html) you can create an override, like:

```
Ext.define('Override.form.field.VTypes', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.VTypes',

    valInt: function(v) {
        return /^(\d+(,\d+)*)?$/.test(v);
    },

    valIntText: 'Must be in the form #,#',

    valIntMask: /[\d\,]/i
});
```

---

In your `app.json` there is a `overrides` key that declares the override directories, it looks like:

```
/**
   * Comma-separated string with the paths of directories or files to search. Any classes
   * declared in these locations will be automatically required and included in the build.
   * If any file defines an Ext JS override (using Ext.define with an "override" property),
   * that override will in fact only be included in the build if the target class specified
   * in the "override" property is also included.
   */
  "overrides": [
    "overrides",
    "${toolkit.name}/overrides"
  ],
```

Comment: I created a different file for this and added the code above. But when i try to use like vtype: 'valInt' in my field, it says like Uncaught TypeError: vtypes[vtype] is not a function

Comment: How do i make that file/component available?

Comment: @yeah i am using Sencha CMD.. but its not picking up. But if i put in same file it does.

Comment: When you say override folder, where i should place this file?

Comment: Hi i created a folder "overrides" inside classic folder and a file CustomValidation.js file inside overrides folder. Is it right? But still i see getting same error.

Comment: I think that's OK (check your `app.json`) but I'd create the file in `overrides/form/field/VTypes.js` instead.

Answer (score 0):

According to @CD..

1) I've found the **overrides** folder in my app

2) put this **VTypes.js** file in the root of **overrides** folder:

```
Ext.override(Ext.form.field.VTypes, {
    digitsOnly: function (value) {
        return this.digitsOnlyRe.test(value);
    },
    digitsOnlyRe: /\\d*$/,
    digitsOnlyText: 'Use digits only!'
});
```

Now all works, thnx all